# In Kendo MVC Grid, how can I use local values for grid initialisation then later use the read operation?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I have the initial values for the grid in my ViewModel. But if the user wants to update values, I want to update my database, then send back the updated values for the grid from the backend. The problem is that the Ajax Read is always called. But it shouldn't because the (initial) values are there in the ViewModel and bound to Grid.

I tried setting the AutoBind to false, but it does not work, I get an error. (Cannot set AutoBind if widget is populated during initialization)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyClass>()
.Name("MyClassGrid")
.BindTo(Model.MyClassList)
.Columns(column =>
    {
        column.Bound(c => c.SomeProp).Title("Some Property");
    })
.Scrollable()
.DataSource(ds => ds
.Ajax()
.Read(read => read.Action("GetMyData", "CheckBar", new { param1 = Model.ParamFirst}))))
```

I want to display the already stored values for my grid, and only use the read operation if I want to update the values in my database too.

Comment: I beleive that within the dataSource you can also do .Update(). That should do what you are asking: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/custom-datasource#custom-datatype-crud-operations-setup

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SQDCDashboard.Core.ViewModels.SafetyIncidentViewModel>()
    .Name("safetyincident-grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedAt).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 22%" }).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Type).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 22%" });
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 22%" });
        columns.ForeignKey(c => c.ProductionLineId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ProductionLines"], "Id", "Name").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 22%" });
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 12%" });
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("New Safety Incident"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(ds =>
        ds.Ajax()
          .ServerOperation(false)
          .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.Id);
                  model.Field(p => p.ProductionLineId).DefaultValue(Model.DefaultProdLine);
           })
           .Read(read => read.Action("GetSafetyIncidentList", "Safety"))
           .Update(update => update.Action("EditSafetyIncidentInLine", "Safety"))
           .Create(create => create.Action("CreateNewSafetyIncident", "Safety"))
           )
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100%" })
     .Sortable()
     .Filterable()
     .Pageable()
     .Mobile()
)
```

Here is an example of my grid.  The `Update(update => update.Action("Action" , "Controller"))`
is the method you are wondering about.  For my code I did not have to pass a parameter in with my read, and I do not need to pass one in with my Update.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditSafetyIncidentInLine([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, SafetyIncidentViewModel sivm)
    {
        if (sivm != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SafetyIncident si = _safetyIncidentService.Find(sivm.Id);
            si.Description = sivm.Description;
            si.ProductionLineId = sivm.ProductionLineId;
            si.ProdLine = _productionLineService.Find(sivm.ProductionLineId);
            si.Type = sivm.Type;

            _safetyIncidentService.Update(si);

            sivm.Id = si.Id;
            sivm.CreatedAt = si.CreatedAt;
        }
        return this.Json(new[] { sivm }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

This method is the one that is called when the Update button is pressed.  The update button is created with the `columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); };` and the `Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))`.  If you want more clarification or if your question is different let me know.  I never got an error with having my grid already initialized when I was updating values.